# Need to make a quad chart that puts 4 small pages in one page within an article document

Tags: flowfram

EDIT: See end of question.

I need to maintain the same outer margins that are defined for the rest of the document, and include a title for the quad chart. Text in one quad shouldn't flow into the other quads or I would have used multicols with horizontal lines. Someone suggested the following in a similar question, but I wasn't sure on how to implement it.

```
\newflowframe{.45\textwidth}{.45\textheight}{0pt}{.55\textheight}
\newflowframe{.45\textwidth}{.45\textheight}{.55\textwidth}{.55\textheight}
\newflowframe{.45\textwidth}{.45\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe{.45\textwidth}{.45\textheight}{.55\textwidth}{0pt}
```

It would be nice if I could control the inner quad margins to use the maximal area possible without detracting from readability.

Working example, sorry about verbose preamble:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PREAMBLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[12pt, paper=letter]{article}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REQUIRED PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[
nochapters, % Turn off chapters since this is an article        
beramono, % Use the Bera Mono font for monospaced text (\texttt)
eulermath,% Use the Euler font for mathematics
pdfspacing, % Makes use of pdftex’ letter spacing capabilities via the microtype package
dottedtoc % Dotted lines leading to the page numbers in the table of contents
]{classicthesis} % The layout is based on the Classic Thesis style

\usepackage{arsclassica} % Modifies the Classic Thesis package

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{Figures/}} % Set the default folder for images

\usepackage{enumitem} % Required for manipulating the whitespace between and within lists

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage{subfig} % Required for creating figures with multiple parts (subfigures)

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} % For including math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\usepackage{varioref} % More descriptive referencing

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEOREM STYLES
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\theoremstyle{definition} % Define theorem styles here based on the definition style (used for definitions and examples)
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{plain} % Define theorem styles here based on the plain style (used for theorems, lemmas, propositions)
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{remark} % Define theorem styles here based on the remark style (used for remarks and notes)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\hypersetup{
%draft, % Uncomment to remove all links (useful for printing in black and white)
colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered,
urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, % Link colors
pdftitle={}, % PDF title
pdfauthor={\textcopyright}, % PDF Author
pdfsubject={}, % PDF Subject
pdfkeywords={}, % PDF Keywords
pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX}, % PDF Creator
pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and ClassicThesis} % PDF producer
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\section}{}{}
%\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\usepackage{soul}
%\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top = 1 in, bottom = 1 in, left = 1 in, right = 1 in}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage[font = small]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem,caption,graphicx}
\captionsetup[figure]{
  font=small,% 10pt
  labelsep=endash
}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!50!black},
    citecolor={cyan!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\headingfont}{Arial}

\linespread{2}

\newcommand{\heading}[1]{%
  \par
  {\large\headingfont #1\par}% 12pt
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}} % The header for all pages (oneside) or for even pages (twoside)
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection~#1}} % Uncomment when using the twoside option - this modifies the header on odd pages
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern1em\color{halfgray} \vline}\color{halfgray}\hspace{0.5em}\rightmark\hfil}} % The header style

\pagestyle{scrheadings} % Enable the headers specified in this block


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLEPAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\normalfont\spacedallcaps{Title}}

\author{\spacedlowsmallcaps{subtitle}}

%\date{\spacedlowsmallcaps{PI: Michael Chapiro}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

%\tableofcontents %might need to make multi-column later to not fill more than a page.

%\vspace{1 cm}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
\lipsum[1-5]
\clearpage

%Quadchart goes here

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I missed the attached document detailing other format requirements. The document specifying the format is on the last two pages of the Broad Agency Announcement, and here are screenshots:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/nxFR99z.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/01pdj2k.png]

I've also found the two images, but example images would be fine:
[image: http://www.uwyo.edu/airrotc/_files/images/af-wings.jpg]

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Air_Force_Research_Laboratory.png]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you need rules between the minipages?

Comment: Added working example. Rules would be good.

Comment: Do you expect us to go and read those last two pages? Please add *all* the requirements to your question.

Comment: Good point, edited.

Comment: You need to edit your preamble - not just for this question, but generally. You are using incompatible packages, loading the same package multiple times and probably some other problematic things. That is, this preamble is inherently problematic and ***will*** cause you numerous headaches. It is worth taking the time to sort it out because not doing so will eat enormous amounts of your time for as long as you are working with it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in LaTeX? Even I, who insists on converting many forms into LaTeX, would do this in LibreOffice. There is zero reason to convert this that I can see. Fill the form in as directed, export it to PDF and include it in your document with `pdfpages`. It is not meant to look typographically pleasing and, if you improve the aesthetics, they'll reject it for failing to comply with the guidelines. It is a template you're meant to fill in. Why make life complicated?

Comment: I was thinking of talking to the program director, but I guess I should probably just do it in LibreOffice.

Comment: I imported the file into LibreOffice and it turns out that this template is really an image... Sets a good precedent for doing everything in LaTeX and importing the PDF into a Word document as images.

Comment: flowframes are for when you WANT text to flow.  Use minipages when you DON'T want text to flow.